# How to combine data and calculate in Excel with formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

Please find attached mention 3 sheets with same heading

```
Section ID  item count  amt gross amt
```

Sheet 1 and  sheet 2 need to add together for whatever matching section and ID  column, Need to add together if section and ID repeating in same sheet or different sheet of sheet 1 and sheet 2 .

Sheet 3 is a negative figure as it item return, so what ever section and ID repeat  in sheet 3 only add together .

Here I can only do by pivot in separate and vlookup for each column and its something like complicated.

Is there any better way for doing it?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Do you mean that to be included in the result, an ID must be repeated *on a single worksheet*? That would explain why only AA and AE are listed in the result, but why is AA listed twice?  AA is not repeated on Sheet3.

Comment: sorry for Inconvenience, Just updated whole thing

Comment: What you described is kind of a database task, Excel is not very good in them. I don't think we could suggest you a much better solution. Maybe a `SUMIFS` instead of VLOOKUP.

Comment: Hii Mate , can you please explain how can we do by SUMIFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

The formulas have been modified to add the data in the Count, Amount, and Gross columns only where there are duplicate values for **both** Location and ID.  The Result table is located on a separate Sheet.

This formula, filled right and down (3 rows only) from C3 in the screenshot below:

`=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C$3:C$6,Sheet1!$B$3:$B$6,$B3,Sheet1!$A$3:$A$6,$A3)+SUMIFS(Sheet2!C$3:C$6,Sheet2!$B$3:$B$6,$B3,Sheet2!$A$3:$A$6,$A3)`

gives the results for the first part.  And this formula, filled right and down from C4, does the second part:

`=SUMIFS(Sheet3!C$3:C$6,Sheet3!$B$3:$B$6,$B6,Sheet3!$A$3:$A$6,$A6)`

[image]

If this answer is not satisfactory, please consult with someone who can help you *clearly* explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thankyou , really what we expect is ,formula which can take column including A and B in result sheet .By checking column A and make unique of column B .And am not sure it is possible in excel

Comment: for result : in sheet 1 if column A = B repeat in same sheet 1 or match with sheet 2 make it consoldate and sum ,if A= B is unique of sheet 1 or 2 then as it is same appear in result .Result sheet is the answer of Sheet 1,2,3 total work

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble understanding you. Are you saying you need a formula to list the unique IDs from sheet 1 and 2? And then the totals should be for Sheets 1, 2 and 3? Before you said Sheet 3 should be listed and totaled separately because the numbers were negative.

Comment: Note that the Result table in my answer is *exactly* what you have shown in your question.  Try to clearly explain what you need that is different.

Comment: Really sheet name result is blank sheet and i need answer same like shows in result sheet. Sheet 1 and sheet 2 add together by combining ,sheet 1 and sheet 2 add if section and ID matches. There are ID and section of sheet 1 repeat in sheet 1 and also there is chance to repeat in sheet 2 also so consoldate and add it .In Sheet 3 is negative figure so if ID and section repeat in same sheet itself mean will consoldate and add negative figure, sheet 3 not add with sheet 1 and 2 .